# Vaadin Flow Upload Component - streaming upload?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am uploading very large files, which exceed the available memory and thus I am using a FileBuffer as Receiver. Unfortunately, when uploading a large file, it takes very long to save it. Instead, I'd much rather start processing the file while it's still uploading.

So is there a way to receive the upload as a stream? Or could I implement my own Receiver, but then do I need to also implement my entire processing logic in that receiver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can implement your own `Receiver`; the built-in receivers like `FileBuffer` and `MemoryBuffer` are just helpers to cover basic use cases. The `Receiver` interface is simple:

```
public interface Receiver extends Serializable {

    /**
     * Invoked when a new upload arrives.
     *
     * @param fileName
     *            the desired filename of the upload, usually as specified by
     *            the client
     * @param mimeType
     *            the MIME type of the uploaded file
     * @return stream to which the uploaded file should be written
     */
    OutputStream receiveUpload(String fileName, String mimeType);
}
```

Your task is to provide the `OutputStream` for the Upload component to write on; in the case of a `FileBuffer`, the class is creating a `File` object and a `FileOutputStream`. If you want to process the stream yourself, you can either extend `FileOutputStream` or create a custom `OutputStream` and implement the `write` method. A `BufferedOutputStream` is also a good option to investigate.

Comment: I have now implemented a class StreamBuffer, which creates a PipedInputStream and a PipedOutputStream and connects them. This generally works, but the receiveUpload method is only called after the data has already been uploaded over the network.The idea was to start processing as soon as the first bits of data arrive.

Comment: @ulim, your code is probably somehow invalid. Checked from Vaadin sources and verified by testing with chrome dev tools that streaming is properly happening while large files are received. Modified UploadFileHandler example in Viritin (does exactly this piped stream dance for you, inverts to API to be more intuitive) to include a UI that shows this in action. https://github.com/viritin/flow-viritin/commit/491ddedc9026b729a6de0516e609c9d52503aa62